# How to prevent third party package CSS from interrupting other components in React

Tags: css, reactjs, aos.js

I'm working on my React web template right now and I ran into this problem where I have fully coded a website and everything works out fine until I decided to import third party CSS in this case AOS (Animate On Scroll) CSS, after import that my navbar (which is in a completely different component) started acting weird, usually that means there is a similar classnames but I'm not sure is there any solution to import CSS on a specific component or maybe other work around

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no solution. The only one is to write good CSS with good and unique selectors to prevent modify other components in the same web.